# make a table output

Tags: text-processing, perl, columns, snmp

if it possible to do a snmpwalk in a perl script and put the output in a table to make a sort of association like for each hostname i have in the same line if index and desc i have the script in bash but the output that i have don't give the association that i want so i need your help

```
#!/bin/bash
Rep_Scripts='/home/scripts'
out_file='/home/scripts/out_file'
rm -rf $Rep_Scripts/out_file

for i in `cat $Rep_Scripts/IP_ALU_LIST.txt | awk '{print}'`
do
read hostname ip <<< $(echo $i |sed 's/;/ /')


        echo "${hostname} ==> ${ip} If_Name" >> out_file
        snmpwalk -v2c -c ${ip} OID>> out_file
        echo "${hostname} ==> ${ip} Global_If_Index" >> out_file
         snmpwalk -v2c -c ${ip} OID >>  out_file
        echo "${hostname} ==> ${ip} If_Statut" >> out_file
        snmpwalk -v2c -c  ${ip} OID >> out_file


done
```

i have in IP_ALU_LIST.txt

```
router2;89.100.12.100
router3;100.100.100.100
```

Comment: Punctuation: please learn to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, refactoring your question:

> How can I construct a perl script that inputs data from snmpwalk for each IP/Host and outputs a table for each OID.

Second, your example `snmpwalk` commands make no sense. It might make sense if `OID` were a variable. You problably mean to use 
    snmpwalk -v2 -c public ${ip} ${OID}

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
# Invoke via $0 <ip-address-file> <OIDs ... >
$input_file=shift @ARGV;
$oids=join(" ",@ARGV);
$oids gt '' || die "Please provide at least one OID for snmpget to fetch"

format STDOUT_TOP = 
@<<<<<<<<<<<  @>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$ip,$hostname
.
format STDOUT = 
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @||||||||||||| @>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$oid,$type,$value
.
$^L="\n\n\n";

# parse inputfile
open(IPFILE,$input_file) or die "Cannot open $input_file";
while (my $host=<IPFILE>) { 
  chomp $host;
  my ($hostname,$ip) = split(";",$host,2);

  open(SNMP,"snmpget -v2 -cpublic $ip $oids |") or die "Cannot run snmpwalk"
  print "$hostname => $ip :\n";
  while ($_ = <SNMP>) { 
       if ( ($oid,$type,$value) = /^(.*?) = ([^:]+): (.*)$/ ) { 
          write
       } else {
          print STDERR  "Could not parse this output:\n  $_";
       }
  }
  $- = 0;
}
```

`snmpget` will output one line for each OID. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/perlform for more on the Perl "format" and the associated `write` command. The `$^L` sets the page-delimiter as three line-feeds instead of the traditional page-eject character (which is CTRL-L). The `$- = 0;` bit essentially forces a new page (with a new header) the next time "write" is called. And the next time it's called, `$hostname` and `$ip` will have new values.

Comment: i have different OID i have three ( description,ifname,ifindex) pliz look to the output that i want following to this link :http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198137/put-data-in-columns?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to reflect more of what I think you want. My answer uses the traditional format...write functionality of perl (which was there since the 1980s!).

Comment: i am trying to execute the script i have an error ** line 26, near "print"** so i think the ipfile is unreachable how i can put the path for txt file to take it this is what i put in the script :$input_file= "/home/scripts/IP_ALU_LIST.txt"  thankyou for your help